# Core data setReturnsDistinctResult not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

So i'm building a small application, it uses core data database of ~25mb size with 4 entities. It's for bus timetables.

In one table named "Stop" there are ~1300 entries of bus stops with atributes "name", "id", "longitude", "latitude" and couple relationships. Now there are many stops with identical name attribute but different coordinates and id. So I want to show all distinct stop names in table view, i'm using setReturnsDistinctResults with NSDictionaryResultType and setPropertiesToFetch. But setReturnsDistinctResult is not working and I'm still getting all entries.

Heres code:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest {
    if (fetchRequest == nil) {
        fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity =  [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Stop" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES] autorelease]];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
        [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"]]];
        [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
        DebugLog(@"fetchRequest initialized");
    }
    return fetchRequest;
}

/////////////////////

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (self.predicateString != nil) {
        self.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.predicateString];
        [self.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    } else {
        self.predicate = nil;
        [self.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }
    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:nil];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}  

//////////////

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Haven't found a solutions. Maybe it's a bug, because strings in name attribute use not only latin alphabet :\. Went on using executeFetchRequest and filtering all entries in array.

Answer (score 4):

This may be late for you, but may help others.

I had the same problem. What I found is that, if persistant store type is **NSSQLiteStoreType** the returnDistinctResults works. But for **NSXMLStoreType** distinct values are not working.

I haven't tested results for NSBinaryStoreType and NSInMemoryStoreType.