# Fetching distinct values of NSInMemoryStoreType returns duplicates. NSSQLiteStoreType does not

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm currently trying to fetch distinct properties from an `NSInMemoryStoreType` store using the following code:

```
- (void)fetchDistinctTitles
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchTitles = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
    [fetchTitles setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [fetchTitles setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [fetchTitles setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"title"]];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedTitles = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchTitles error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedTitles);
}
```

Using an `NSSQLiteStoreType` store works like expected. Instead, using `NSInMemoryStoreType` returns duplicated `title`'s.

Here is my sample code, based on Apple's "Master-Detail Application" template: http://cl.ly/1K001N3e3x1U. Switch the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s store type in the app delegate and add some entries to determine the different results in the log.

Is this a known issue or did I miss something in the `NSFetchRequest`?

Comment: That looks like an (undocumented) restriction of NSInMemoryStoreType. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/5014226/1187415 where the same problem was reported for NSXMLStoreType.

Comment: Ok, I see. Would you please add your comment inkl. the link as an answer, so I can mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From my above comment:) That looks like a restriction of `NSInMemoryStoreType`,
however, it is not documented in [*Persistent Store Features*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdPersistentStores.html) of the "Core Data Programming Guide".

The same problem was reported for the `NSXMLStoreType` in the answer to *[Core data setReturnsDistinctResult not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834282/core-data-setreturnsdistinctresult-not-working)*.

It might be worth to file a bug report.