# Core Data fetch distinct values of property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'd like to do the following:

```
Select distinct department
From employees
Order By department
```

(The order by part is optional).

Employees contains Person objects, which have a name and a department property.

I've looked through a whole lot of questions like this, however it's not working for me. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
AppDelegate *applicationDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [applicationDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *personEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[personEntity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"department"]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error) {
    ALog(@"%@",error);
} else {
    return result;
}
```

For the content of:

```
Name | Department
P1   | D1
P2   | D1
P3   | D2
```

The above code gives me an array of 3 NSDictionaries, like this:

```
{
    department = D1
}
{
    department = D1
}
{
    department = D2
}
```

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: Well, executing the select I write in SQL, it would only return [D1,D2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has the same problem:

What I found is that, if persistent store type is NSSQLiteStoreType the returnDistinctResults works. But for NSXMLStoreType distinct values are not working.

[Credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834282/core-data-setreturnsdistinctresult-not-working/5014226#5014226).