# core data fetch request does not return distinct results

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to return distinct results from a core-data entity to then put into a popup menu. I only want entity with the requested property to appear in the returned dictionary one time so that it could then be used as a predicate for another popup.

e.g.
records:

name  |  id

Test1 | 111

Test1 | 222

Test2 | 333

would return 
`Test1`
`Test2`

So this could be set as a predicate for a `NSPopUpButton` for `name`. When the user selects that name it would set a second popup with a content set of corresponding values.

e.g.
Name popup with `Test1` as selected object yields
ID popup with a content set of `111` and `222`

---

So I started with this fetch request, based on articles I read here on SO.

```
-(void)fetchItems {

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Equipment"];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Equipment" inManagedObjectContext:[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext]];

        fetchRequest.entity = entity;

        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"item"]];
        fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
        [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

        NSArray *dictionaries = [[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
        NSLog (@"names: %@",dictionaries);
}
```

However the NSLog still returns Nondistinct records! This is the log:

```
names: (
    {
    item = item2;
},
    {
    item = item1;
},
    {
    item = item1;
}
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this fetch isn't executing properly? Also, based on what I have explained that I want to do, am I on the right track with the logic? 
Thanks

Comment: Your code seems correct. As far as I remember, you don't have to use `[entity propertiesByName]`. Simple `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"item"]` should be enough

Comment: thanks for simplifying that line. You're right. But the query still isn't pulling distinct results.

Comment: I have no idea then... Are you using `NSSQLiteStoreType`? According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5014226/2128900 `setReturnsDistinctResults` may not work with the other store types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collection object `NSSet`...

Following this line in your `fetchItems` method:

```
NSArray *dictionaries = [[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Add this line:

```
NSSet *setDictionaries = [NSSet setWithArray:dictionaries];
```

Change your log:

```
NSLog (@"names: %@",setDictionaries);
```

Refer to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Also helpful [About Collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i)